# Error converting to Pandas Datetime to include only the time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have made a new column in my dataframe that's the difference between two other `datetime64` columns, with precision to the seconds.  The other two columns have been created using the following format:

```
df = df.col1.values.astype('datetime64[s]')
df = df.col2.values.astype9('datetime64[s]')
df.col3 = df.col2 - df.col1
```

*df.col3* values have format '%H:%M:%S', and I don't want the date (just time difference).  I've tried the following command:

```
df.col3 = pd.to_datetime(df.col3, format='%H:%M:%S')
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: time data 1154000000000L does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
>   (match)

I was wondering why this error is occurring, and what I can do to convert this time difference into a format that can eventually be used for sorting purposes. Thanks.

EDIT: The Dataframe in question has the following format:

```
             col1           col2                   col3       IDval
0    2015-01-10 19:31:59 2015-01-10 19:51:13      00:19:14   949560
1    2015-01-10 19:31:52 2015-01-10 19:51:13      00:19:21   949560
2    2015-01-10 19:31:59 2015-01-10 19:51:53      00:19:54   949560
3    2015-01-10 19:31:52 2015-01-10 19:51:53      00:20:01   949560
4    2015-01-10 19:31:59 2015-01-10 19:51:53      00:19:54   949560
5    2015-01-10 19:31:52 2015-01-10 19:51:53      00:20:01   949560
```

This is just an example of a few columns in my dataframe: multiple rows for each *IDVAL*, in which each row has a different *col3*.  Eventually, I'd like to extract all rows in between `0:00 - 9:30`, using the `between_time` command.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you put the dataframe in your question? Would be easy to debug.

Comment: I've edited the original post, thanks.

Comment: I dont quite understand the question. When I do the df.col2 - df.col1,I get          0   00:19:14
1   00:19:21
2   00:19:54
3   00:20:01
4   00:19:54
5   00:20:01 which is only the time difference right?

Comment: The subtraction works.  However, when attempting to use column 3 in another dataframe function, such as indexing by time using the between_time command, I run into errors.  Would it be possible to convert the above col3 into a string, and then into a time format that can be used in subsequent functions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after you do this step:

`df['final'] = df.col3 - df.col2` which gives

00:19:14 1
00:19:21 2
00:19:54 3
00:20:01 4
00:19:54 5
00:20:01 6

`df['final'] = pd.to_datetime(df['final'])`

```
df['final']
```

1970-01-01 00:19:14 1
1970-01-01 00:19:21 2
1970-01-01 00:19:54 3
1970-01-01 00:20:01 4
1970-01-01 00:19:54 5
1970-01-01 00:20:01 6
Name: final, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Create an index column

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['final'])
```

and then do

```
df['final'].between_time('00:19:14','00:19:54')
```

Which gives the result you want. You just need to strip "1970-01-01" from the result. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you Gayatri for your help.  Your solution has solved my issue.  I was wondering why creating an index column would make this script work?